# PHP Licence key with remote MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I created an database with this table

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `software` (
  `ID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CompanyName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `valid` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `license` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

and make a licence.php on another server to connect with remote mysql

```
        <?php
    function connect(){
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=NAME;host=xx.xx.xx.xx';
$user = 'USER';
$password = 'PASS';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    // run query
    $license = "test";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM software WHERE license='$license' AND valid='1'");
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    if ($sth->rowCount() < 1) {
        die("Your License Has Expired!");
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}
    ?>
```

Update:nothing happened!! just blank page in both way (valid=0) or (valid=1)

What is the problem?

Comment: `$sth = $dbh = ` to `$sth = $dbh->prepare `?

Comment: you are ending the function `connect` on line 11, move that `}` to just before `?>` then call the method, or just remove the method all together

Comment: You aren't calling `connect()` anywhere either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're defining the `connect()` function and not calling it. It seems like redundant coding that you have going on.

You should simply just run something like this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=NAME;host=xx.xx.xx.xx';
$user = 'USER';
$password = 'PASS';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    // run query
    $license = "test";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM software WHERE license='$license' AND valid='1'");
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    if ($sth->rowCount() < 1) {
        die("Your License Has Expired!");
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also, instead of doing:

```
if (count($result) === 0) {
```

You should use the native PDO `rowCount`

```
if($sth->rowCount() < 1) {....
```

The above will check if the row count is less than 1 (*effectively* **`0`**)

Comment: no error! but nothing happened and page is blank!!! i set valid row to 0 and 1 but in both way page is blank

Comment: i still looking for answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `$dbh` does not exist outside of your `connect()` function. If you want to use it outside you have to return it.

```
function connect(){
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=NAME;host=xx.xx.xx.xx';
        $user = 'USER';
        $password = 'PASS';    
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
        return $dbh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `connect()` function,

`$sth = $dbh = (`
should probably be `$sth = $dbh->prepare(`

Comment: could you give me the completed code? yo mean this?

Comment: i add this $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM software WHERE license='$license' AND valid='1'"); but this error:Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/travia22/public_html/test/agb.php on line 13